# PHP: Creating cropped thumbnails of images, problems

Tags: php, image, resize, thumbnails

I am fairly new to PHP, and I am writing a script that will resize images.

First an uploaded image is resized to 800width by *height, depending on the orientation of the file uploaded (portrait/landscape).

The script is then meant to create a thumbnail of that image. The thumbnail must be 175width by 117height. This is has the same proportion as a standard jpeg image from the cameras that take the pictures, thus there is no need to crop the image for a thumbnail version if the original file is landscape. However, when the uploaded image is portrait orientation I must crop image to be able to achieve a thumbnail of 175x117px. When cropping, I need to maintain the center of the image (as opposed to the top left, bottom right, etc.)

I am having massive trouble doing this, and I would really be eternally grateful if someone would mind taking the time to look through my code and help me out! :D

The site can be found at hybridtempo.net. Beware that there is some pretty random shit in the database, where I had to enter random data and ran out of ideas, lol.

Everything seems to work fine until very near the bottom, where I begin to use the 'imagecopyresize', 'imagecreatetruecolour', 'imagecreatefromjpeg', etc. functions.

Thanks very much for any contribution. :)

Without further ado:

```
<?php


//IMAGE RESIZE FUNCTION CODE BEGIN - CODE FOUND AND APPROPRIATED FROM http://github.com/maxim/smart_resize_image/

function smart_resize_image($file,
                              $width              = 0, 
                              $height             = 0, 
                              $proportional       = false, 
                              $output             = 'file', 
                              $delete_original    = true, 
                              $use_linux_commands = false ) {

    if ( $height <= 0 && $width <= 0 ) return false;

    # Setting defaults and meta
    $info                         = getimagesize($file);
    $image                        = '';
    $final_width                  = 0;
    $final_height                 = 0;
    list($width_old, $height_old) = $info;

    # Calculating proportionality
    if ($proportional) {
      if      ($width  == 0)  $factor = $height/$height_old;
      elseif  ($height == 0)  $factor = $width/$width_old;
      else                    $factor = min( $width / $width_old, $height / $height_old );

      $final_width  = round( $width_old * $factor );
      $final_height = round( $height_old * $factor );
    }
    else {
      $final_width = ( $width <= 0 ) ? $width_old : $width;
      $final_height = ( $height <= 0 ) ? $height_old : $height;
    }

    # Loading image to memory according to type
    switch ( $info[2] ) {
      case IMAGETYPE_GIF:   $image = imagecreatefromgif($file);   break;
      case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:  $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);  break;
      case IMAGETYPE_PNG:   $image = imagecreatefrompng($file);   break;
      default: return false;
    }


    # This is the resizing/resampling/transparency-preserving magic
    $image_resized = imagecreatetruecolor( $final_width, $final_height );
    if ( ($info[2] == IMAGETYPE_GIF) || ($info[2] == IMAGETYPE_PNG) ) {
      $transparency = imagecolortransparent($image);

      if ($transparency >= 0) {
        $transparent_color  = imagecolorsforindex($image, $trnprt_indx);
        $transparency       = imagecolorallocate($image_resized, $trnprt_color['red'], $trnprt_color['green'], $trnprt_color['blue']);
        imagefill($image_resized, 0, 0, $transparency);
        imagecolortransparent($image_resized, $transparency);
      }
      elseif ($info[2] == IMAGETYPE_PNG) {
        imagealphablending($image_resized, false);
        $color = imagecolorallocatealpha($image_resized, 0, 0, 0, 127);
        imagefill($image_resized, 0, 0, $color);
        imagesavealpha($image_resized, true);
      }
    }
    imagecopyresampled($image_resized, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $final_width, $final_height, $width_old, $height_old);

    # Taking care of original, if needed
    if ( $delete_original ) {
      if ( $use_linux_commands ) exec('rm '.$file);
      else @unlink($file);
    }

    # Preparing a method of providing result
    switch ( strtolower($output) ) {
      case 'browser':
        $mime = image_type_to_mime_type($info[2]);
        header("Content-type: $mime");
        $output = NULL;
      break;
      case 'file':
        $output = $file;
      break;
      case 'return':
        return $image_resized;
      break;
      default:
      break;
    }

    # Writing image according to type to the output destination
    switch ( $info[2] ) {
      case IMAGETYPE_GIF:   imagegif($image_resized, $output);    break;
      case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:  imagejpeg($image_resized, $output);   break;
      case IMAGETYPE_PNG:   imagepng($image_resized, $output);    break;
      default: return false;
    }

    return true;
  }


//IMAGE RESIZE FUNCTION CODE END.



/******** IMAGE UPLOAD SCRIPT BEGIN ********/

//IF IMAGE IS JPEG OR PNG
if (($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
{
    //IF THERE IS AN ERROR, DISPLAY THE MESSAGE
    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
        echo "<p>Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "
        <br />
        Redirecting...
        <br />
        <br />
        If you are not automatically redirected after 3 seconds, <b><a href='addproduct_uploadimage.php'>click here to try another upload.</a></p>";

        //REDIRECT
        echo "<META HTTP-EQUIV='refresh' CONTENT='3;URL=addproduct_uploadimage.php'>";
    }

    //OTHERWISE, PROCEED
    else
    {
        //EXPLAIN CURRENT PROCESS TO USER
        echo "<p>File Uploaded: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
        echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
        echo "Temporary file stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "</p><br /><br />";

        //ABSOLUTE PATH OF FILE
        $img_url = "/home/space_/hybridtempo.net/images/uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];

        //IF FILE ALREADY EXISTS, TELL THE USER IT ALREADY EXISTS, REDIRECT TO TRY AGAIN
        if (file_exists($img_url))
        {
            echo "<p>" . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. Redirecting...
            <br />
            <br />
            If you are not automatically redirected after 3 seconds, <b><a href='addproduct_uploadimage.php'>click here to try another upload.</a></p>";

            echo "<META HTTP-EQUIV='refresh' CONTENT='3;URL=addproduct_uploadimage.php'>";
        }

        //IF FILE DOES NOT ALREADY EXIST, PROCEED...
        else
        {
            //POSITION - FROM THE ABSOLUTE ROOT OF THE CLIENT'S WEBSPACE - FOR THE FILE TO GET STORED
            $img_url                =   "/home/space_/hybridtempo.net/images/uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];                       
            $thumb_url              =   "/home/space_/hybridtempo.net/images/uploads/thumbnails/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];    

            //MOVE TEMPORARY FILE TO WHERE IT IT SHOULD BE STORED
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $img_url);

            // FIND IMAGE WIDTH AND HEIGHT TO DETRMINE RESIZE DIMENSIONS
            list($width, $height) = getimagesize($img_url);

            // RESIZE BASED ON PORTRAIT OR LANDSCAPE ORIENTATION OF IMAGE
            if ($width > $height)
            {
                smart_resize_image($img_url,
                                      $width              = 800, 
                                      $height             = 0, 
                                      $proportional       = true, 
                                      $output             = 'file', 
                                      $delete_original    = true, 
                                      $use_linux_commands = false );


                    // STORE URL OF IMAGE IN 'picture' TABLE in 'shop' DATABASE
                    mysql_connect("**************","***********","*****");  
                    mysql_select_db("hybridtempo_shop");
                    $prod_id = $_SESSION["prod_id"];
                    $result = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO picture (prod_id,picture_url,picture_id) VALUES ('$prod_id', '$img_url', 'NULL')");
                    mysql_close();                  


                smart_resize_image($img_url,
                                      $width              = 175, 
                                      $height             = 117, 
                                      $proportional       = false, 
                                      $output             = $thumb_url, 
                                      $delete_original    = false, 
                                      $use_linux_commands = false );


                    // STORE URL OF IMAGE IN 'picture' TABLE in 'shop' DATABASE
                    mysql_connect("******************","****************","***********"); 
                    mysql_select_db("hybridtempo_shop");
                    $prod_id = $_SESSION["prod_id"];
                    $result = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO picture (prod_id,thumbnail_url,picture_id) VALUES ('$prod_id', '$thumb_url', 'NULL')");
                    mysql_close();
            }                         

            else
            {
                smart_resize_image($img_url,
                                      $width              = 0, 
                                      $height             = 700, 
                                      $proportional       = true, 
                                      $output             = 'file', 
                                      $delete_original    = true, 
                                      $use_linux_commands = false ); 


                    // STORE URL OF IMAGE IN 'picture' TABLE in 'shop' DATABASE
                    mysql_connect("*********","**********","**********"); 
                    mysql_select_db("hybridtempo_shop");
                    $prod_id = $_SESSION["prod_id"];
                    $result = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO picture (prod_id,picture_url,picture_id) VALUES ('$prod_id', '$img_url', 'NULL')");
                    mysql_close();                    


                    $wrongsize_thumb_url    =   $_FILES["file"]["name"];

                    smart_resize_image  ($img_url,
                                        $width              = 175, 
                                        $height             = 0, 
                                        $proportional       = true, 
                                        $output             = $wrongsize_thumb_url, 
                                        $delete_original    = false, 
                                        $use_linux_commands = false 
                                        );


                    //FUNCTION FROM WIDELY SUPPORTED GD LIBRARY, BUNDLED WITH PHP

                    $wrongsize_thumb_url    =   $_FILES["file"]["name"];

                    //CROP PORTRAIT THUMBNAILS, AS THEY ARE TOO TALL.


                    $image_for_resize   =   ImageCreateFromJpeg($wrongsize_thumb_url);

                    $temporary_image    =   imagecreatetruecolor(117,175);

                    imagecopyresized    (
                                        $temporary_image, $image_for_resize,
                                        $destination_x_coordinate       =   0,
                                        $destination_y_coordinate       =   0,
                                        $source_x_coordinate            =   0,
                                        $source_y_coordinate            =   58,
                                        $destination_width              =   175,
                                        $destination_height             =   117,
                                        $source_width                   =   175,
                                        $source_height                  =   261
                                        );

                    imagejpeg       ($image_for_resize, 'thumbnail_' . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);

                    imagedestroy    ($wrongsize_thumb_url);


                    // STORE URL OF IMAGE IN 'picture' TABLE in 'shop' DATABASE
                    mysql_connect("************","*************","***************"); 
                    mysql_select_db("hybridtempo_shop");
                    $prod_id = $_SESSION["prod_id"];
                    $result = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO picture (prod_id,thumbnail_url,picture_id) VALUES ('$prod_id', '$thumb_url', 'NULL')");
                    mysql_close();  
            }


            //EXPLAIN WHERE IMAGE AND THUMBNAIL WERE STORED AND INFORM OF IMINENT REDIRECT
            echo "<p>Image stored in: " . $_img_url;
            echo "<br />";
            echo "<p>Thumbnail stored in: " . $thumb_url;
            echo "<br /><br />";

            // UNSET PROD_ID VARIABLE TO PREVENT MIXUPS IF ADDING ANOTHER PRODUCT
            unset($_SESSION['prod_id']);

            //REDIRECTION MESSAGE
            echo "If you are not automatically redirected after 5 seconds, <b><a href='index.php'>click here to return to the homepage.</a></p>";

            //REDIRECT TO HOMEPAGE
            //echo "<META HTTP-EQUIV='refresh' CONTENT='5;URL=index.php'>";


        }
    }
}
else
    {
    echo "<p>Error: The file needs to be an image. Redirecting...
    <br />
    <br />
    If you are not automatically redirected after 3 seconds, <b><a href='addproduct_uploadimage.php'>click here to try another upload.</a></b></p>";
    //REDIRECT
    echo "<META HTTP-EQUIV='refresh' CONTENT='3;URL=addproduct_uploadimage.php'>";
    }
?>







        </center>

      </div>    

      <div class="nav_bar">
    <p><i>  ~<a href="index.php"> home </a>~
            <a href="http://blog.hybridtempo.net/"> blog </a>~
            <a href="shop.php"> shop </a>~
            <a href="#">  sourcing </a>~                                        <!-- Navigation bar contents. !-->
            <a href="#"> links </a>~
            <a href="#"> about </a>~
            <a href="#"> contact </a>~  </i></p>

      </div>

    </div>


    <div id="bg">
      <div>
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <img src="images/bg.jpg" alt=""/>                       <!-- Background image. Must match thumbnail on homepage navigation grid !-->
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
</div>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You are not really asking a question are you? Where are you stuck? What doesn't work as it should?

Comment: You might have better luck using ImageMagick http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/thumbnails/

Answer (score 0):

Look at **example 1**: at following URL.  It shows a very simple script for resizing images in PHP:

http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresized.php